# Can't receive correct answer from Squareup API

Tags: node.js, request, square-connect

I'm trying to send a post message to Square to create an item

```
var postData = {
        "name": "Milkshake",
        "variations": [
                        {
                            "name": "Small",
                            "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
                            "price_money": {
                                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                                "amount": 400
                                            }
                        }
                    ]}

request.post({
uri:"https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/items",
headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
             'Accept':        'application/json',
             'Content-Type':  'application/json'},
body: querystring.stringify(postData)
},function(err,res,body){
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(body); });
```

But I receive this message from Square

```
{"type":"bad_request","message":"invalid json"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you used `querystring.stringify`, which produces a URL encoded request body. You want `JSON.stringify` to produce a JSON encoded body. I.E:

```
request.post({
uri:"https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/items",
headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
             'Accept':        'application/json',
             'Content-Type':  'application/json'},
body: JSON.stringify(postData)
},function(err,res,body){
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(body); });
```